# Filter Json object attribute to add css style

Tags: php, javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

Your help appreciate to learn the way to do this, Lets say I have a code similar to this one.

**Backbone script:**

```
$(function(){
  var Band = Backbone.Model.extend();
    var BandList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Band,
    url: 'feed1.json'
  });

  var BandsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#bandlist_template').html()),
    render: function(eventName) {
      _.each(this.model.models, function(band){
        var lTemplate = this.template(band.toJSON());

        $(this.el).append(lTemplate);
      }, this);
      return this;
    }
  });

  var lBands = new BandList;

  var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "body",

    render: function(){
      var lBandsView = new BandsView({model:lBands});
      var lHtml = lBandsView.render().el;
      $('#bands').html(lHtml);
    },

    initialize: function(){
      var lOptions = {};
      lOptions.success = this.render;
      lBands.fetch(lOptions);
    }
  });

  var App = new AppView;
});
```

**Underscore js Template:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="bandlist_template">
  <?php echo "hello"; ?><li><%= band_name %> - <%= section %></li>
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="bands">
</ul>
```

**Json:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "149",
    "band_name": "Armthorpe Elmfield",
    "section": "Fourth"
  },
  {
    "id": "127",
    "band_name": "Barnsley Chronicle",
    "section": "Second"
  },
  {
    "id": "155",
    "band_name": "Barnsley Metropolitan Band",
    "section": "Fourth"
  }
]
```

Ok. Lets say I want to change `css` style according to `json` `section` attribute (just only need to put div and style only json `section` attribute is `'Fourth'`). So how to filter that attribute and push it into another backbone js populated `div` inside the same `ul`.

**Just like this one:**

```
<ul id="bands">
</li>Armthorpe Elmfield - <div class="styled">Fourth</div><li>
</li>Barnsley Chronicle - Second<li>
</li>Barnsley Metropolitan Band - <div class="styled">Fourth</div><li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything you need, just use the template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="bandlist_template">
    <?php echo "hello"; ?>
    <li><%= band_name %> - 
        <% if section is 'Fourth': %>
            <div class="styled">Fourth</div>
        <% else: %>
            <%= section %>
        <% end %>
    </li>
</script>
```

Of course it could be made better but just to prove the point that `if` and other control structure work no problem in your templates. (In the example I am using `eco` syntax in the if, just fix it to use normal javascript if you need it).